# I want run PowerShell commands using administrator with normal PowerShell user

Tags: powershell

I want execute following command without opening admin PowerShell prompt.It should be execute on normal prompt. like we are `sudo useradd <username>` in Linux.

```
Enable-PSRemoting; 
Set-Item wsman:\\localhost\\client\\trustedhosts $hostIP -Force;
Restart-Service WinRM
```

I am going integrate this code into C#. Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible. 
Allowing that would be a major security issue in Windows.

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking is not possible directly from a PowerShell script, at least as far as I know. What you can do is create a scheduled task running that script with admin privileges, and then invoke the scheduled task as a normal user.